# Angular2 : get parent router data

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm creating a component under route /blabla/:id/blabla/:secondid

First part of my url "/blabla/:id/..." is managed by my first routing component.

Then, a second router manages the second part of url.

In my component, I can easy access to my ":secondid" in RouteData.

But I wonder how I can access my ":id" from there.

Any idea ?

Comment: simple use `RouteParams` to send `id` while routing

Comment: How can I do this ? In my second router, I can access to my routeParams in my constructor to know the value of the first :id. But how can I propagate this to my routes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the first `id` along with data-binding.

Comment: How can you bind data to your component while routing ?
Second router looks like this
@Component({...template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'...})
@RouteConfig([{path: '/blabla/:id', name: 'SecondRouting', component: FinalComponent}])
How can I bind any stuff to FinalComponent?

Comment: K I think I found my answer there : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4452

Answer (score 2):

You must use `Injector` to get parents data.

This is a sample code extrated from [here](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/) using the feature.

```
    this.params = injector.parent.parent.get(RouteParams);
    this.userLogin = this.params.get('userLogin');
```

Take a look at the constructor and how the `injector` is used to get the great parent's `userLogin`

```
import {Component, Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouteParams, RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="" />
      <p *ngIf="userData.name">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> 

      </p>
      <p *ngIf="userData.company">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i> 

      </p>
      <p *ngIf="userData.location">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> 

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">

    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    img { width: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  `]
})

export class UserDetail {
  params: RouteParams;
  userLogin: string;
  userData: Object = {};

  constructor(public http: Http, params: RouteParams, injector: Injector, private _router: Router) {
    // We use injector to get a hold of the parent's params
    this.params = injector.parent.parent.get(RouteParams);
    this.userLogin = this.params.get('userLogin');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(`http://api.github.com/users/${this.userLogin}`)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.userData = data,
        err => console.log(err)
      );
  }

}
```

Comment: This no longer seems to work as of [Angular 2.0.0-beta.16 (2016-04-26)](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1)